# specific word for this term

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

"After rain, when raindrops _________ on leaves and falls intermittently with blow of wind."

I want to say here raindrops (collected) (stayed) on the leaves but it doesn't seem appropriate at all. So which word can be used here.

P.S. Its a romantic novel.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *settle*? BTW, the sentence needs more corrections.

Comment: The sentence needs so many corrections that this amounts to proofreading. (No matter what verb you put in the blank, the result will not be English.) You've got a great top answer that fixes everything for you, but please don't ask such questions in the future, with such poor titles to boot. You can take them to chat, for which you have sufficient reputation.

Answer (score 4):

"After rain, when raindrops **linger** on leaves and fall intermittently as the wind blows."

> linger:
>
> 1. to remain or stay on in a place longer than is usual or anticipated.
> 2. to remain alive, continue to persist, although gradually dying, ceasing, disappearing, etc.

([Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/linger))

> *Forgotten lives linger like raindrops on leaves that will soon fall...* ([Poem Hunter](http://www.poemhunter.com/poem/a-forgotten-word/))

Answer (score 2):

when raindrops **bead** on leaves, ...

> "bead" definition (noun): a drop of liquid, a bubble rising through
>   effervescent liquid. Usually plural, beads are a mass of such bubbles
>   on the surface of a liquid.
>
> "bead" definition (verb): forming beads.

*Photo of raindrops beading on a water proofed deck*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Trickles - (of a liquid) flow in a small stream.
For example - "a solitary tear trickled down her cheek"
or

Caress(just to make it romantic) - touch or stroke gently or lovingly.
For example : "she felt the caress of his breath on her cheek"

Comment: It's a delightful image, but this answer is likely to be deleted unless you  explain how it meets the requirements of the question (viz. "collected", "stayed").

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, accumulate?

> to gather or acquire (something) gradually as time passes

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accumulate